# How to pin openstack container versions when using kolla-ansible?

Tags: openstack, docker-registry

When installing openstack via kolla-ansible you specify openstack version in globals.yml, ie:  openstack_release: "victoria".  This is as specific as you can get, there are no point-in-time tags, just a moving target like "victoria".

In my experience containers are updated randomly, not all-at-once, and frequently.  Every time I rebuild I'm having to wait for docker to pull down things which have changed since my last deploy.  This is problematic for multiple reasons, most acutely:

- This is a fast-moving community-driven project.  I'm having to work through new issues every few times I rebuild as a result of changes.
- If I deploy onto one set of hosts, then deploy onto more hosts hours later, I'm waiting again on updates, and my stack is running containers of different versions.
- These pulls take time and make my deployments vulnerable to timeouts and network problems.

To emphasize what a problem the second issue is, usually I can reset a failed deployment and try again, but not always.  There have been times where I had residual issues, and due to my noobness it was quicker to dump fresh disks and start over.  I'm using external ceph (the only ceph option in kolla-ansible:victoria), colocated with the compute nodes.  Resetting pool / OSD state to an earlier point in time isn't in my toolbox yet, so I also wipe my OSD's and redo the ceph installation.   I can pin version on ceph containers, but I start to sweat once the kolla-ansible installation starts.   For a 4-hour total install, there's a not-small chance that another container will change in this time.

The obvious answer for anybody who does IT or software professionally is to pin my kolla:* container versions to a specific point-in-time tag, and not "victoria".   I could pin each container to a digest, but that's not supported in the playbooks as written.  I'd need to edit ansible playboooks and add a variable for every container that I want to pin.  And then maintain that logic as new containers are added.  I'm pulling 43 containers right now.  This approach feels like "2 trailer park girls go 'round the outside".

A far simpler approach which I'm planning is to pull all the "victoria"-tagged containers, and then iterate through pushing them back into my own docker repo (eg, "victoria-feralcoder-20120321"), and then update globals.yml to use this stable tag.  I'm new to managing my own docker repos, so I don't know if I can retag images in a pull-through cache, or if I need to set up a private repo for that, so I may also have to switch kolla-ansible between docker.io and a private feralcoder repo, depending on whether I want to do a latest-pull or a pinned-pull.   That would be a little "hey nineteen", cleaner and nicer, still not quite right...

I feel like this pull-retag-push-reconfigure-redeploy approach is hack jankery.   Does anybody have a better suggestion?  Like, to not check upstream for container changes if there's already a tag-match in the local mirror?   Or maybe a way to pull-thru-and-retag, at the registry level?

Thanks, in advance, and also thanks to the kolla-ansible contributors for all their work, short of not providing version stability.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current preferred solution, which is still, admittedly, a hack:

Pull the latest images as a batch, then tag them and push them to a local registry.

First, I need 2 docker registries: I can't push to a pull-through cache, so I also needed to set up a private registry, which I can push to.

I need to toggle settings in globals.yml back and forth during kolla-ansible deploy to achieve this:

- When I run "kolla-ansible bootstrap-servers" I need the local registry configured, so that stack hosts are configured with appropriate insecure-registries configs.
- I use "kolla-ansible pull" to prefetch the latest packages, when I want to update.  For this I reconfigure globals.yml to point at kolla/*:victoria.
- After I fetch the latest containers, I run a loop on one of my stack hosts to pull them from my pull-through cache, tag them to my local registry with a date stamp tag, and push them to my local registry.
- Before I run the actual deploy I configure globals.yml to use my local registry and tags.

These are the globals.yml settings of interest:

```
## PINNED CONTAINER VERSIONS
#docker_registry: 192.168.127.220:4001
#docker_namespace: "feralcoder"
#openstack_release: "feralcoder-20210321"

# LATEST CONTAINER VERSIONS
docker_registry:
docker_registry_username: feralcoder
docker_namespace: "kolla"
openstack_release: "victoria"
```

My pseudocode is like this (intermediate steps pruned...):

```
use_localized_containers () {
  cp $KOLLA_SETUP_DIR/files/kolla-globals-localpull.yml /etc/kolla/globals.yml
  cat $KOLLA_SETUP_DIR/files/kolla-globals-remainder.yml >> /etc/kolla/globals.yml
}

use_latest_dockerhub_containers () {
  # We switch to dockerhub container fetches, to get the latest "victoria" containers
  cp $KOLLA_SETUP_DIR/files/kolla-globals-dockerpull.yml /etc/kolla/globals.yml
  cat $KOLLA_SETUP_DIR/files/kolla-globals-remainder.yml >> /etc/kolla/globals.yml
}

localize_latest_containers () {
  for CONTAINER in `ls $KOLLA_PULL_THRU_CACHE`; do
    ssh_control_run_as_user root "docker image pull kolla/$CONTAINER:victoria" $PULL_HOST
    ssh_control_run_as_user root "docker image tag kolla/$CONTAINER:victoria $LOCAL_REGISTRY/feralcoder/$CONTAINER:$TAG" $PULL_HOST
    ssh_control_run_as_user root "docker image push $LOCAL_REGISTRY/feralcoder/$CONTAINER:$TAG" $PULL_HOST
  done
}

use_localized_containers 
kolla-ansible -i $INVENTORY  bootstrap-servers
use_latest_dockerhub_containers
kolla-ansible -i $INVENTORY pull
localize_latest_containers
use_localized_containers
kolla-ansible -i $INVENTORY deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one answer, for an existing deployment:

If you have already pulled containers to all your hosts, you can edit some ansible or python so that docker_container.pull=false for all containers.

This is the implementing module:
.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/docker/docker_container.py.
This file might be in /usr/local/share/kolla-ansible/, or .../venvs/kolla-ansible/.  When false, if the container exists on the host it won't be repulled.

This doesn't help the situation where a host hasn't yet pulled the package and you have a version already in your local mirror.  In that situation, the stack host will pull the container, and your pull-through cache will pull down any container updates since last pull.